# How to call different functions of different apps by user agent in django?

Tags: python, django, user-agent

I have the following Django project structure wherein I have two functions named 'get_profile' on both views (ie. app1/views and app2/views). I want to open get_profile function from app1 in case if the user agent is desktop otherwise from app2.

```
>>project
  --urls.py
>>app1
    -- views.py
    -- urls.py
>>app2
    -- views.py
    -- urls.py
```

Any suggestions on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would handle this in a middleware function and redirect the user to the appropriate URL based on the user agent.

Comment: You can't have the same url pointing to two different views. Either redirect from one view to the other (using a different url) or make a generic view that calls the other views directly to fetch the response depending on the UA.

Comment: @themanatuf: I want to create same url for these issues, for example /get-profile will be the url created in app1.

Comment: @dirkgroten: Can I create any custom generic middleware which can do the same? I mean route on the basis of UA.

Comment: May I suggest there's something of a design smell here ? Why on earth would you want to do such a thing ?

Comment: Can’t think of a good way. I agree with Bruno though, having one view where you need to differentiate on UA sounds plausible, but generic for all your views? That really doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: I don't have to create this for all views, I just want to create for some common urls, like get-profile, homepage etc. Actually, I want to do this with a custom middleware, however there's something I have found from django docs which is 'reverse'

Comment: @ShubhamKUMAR it's not a matter of how many views are concerned - even if only for one single url, I fail to see any reason to have it dynamically dispatched to one app or another depening on the UA. So I repeat my question (which you didn't answer): __Why on earth would you want to do such a thing ?__  (nb: you may want to [read about XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I knew this is not a good way to route like this but as already said this is the requirement which I need to do and moreover project structure is like that only which I have shared on my question.

Comment: @ShubhamKUMAR your question states that you "want" to do it this way - you don't mention that this is "a requirement"  (nor any other constraint FWIW).